# How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function

Tags: php, variadic-functions

I have a PHP function that takes a variable number of arguments (using `func_num_args()` and `func_get_args()`), but the number of arguments I want to pass the function depends on the length of an array. Is there a way to *call* a PHP function with a variable number of arguments?

Comment: Check my answer to learn about a splat operator in new php5.6: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23163963/1090562

Answer (score 136, accepted):

If you have your arguments in an array, you might be interested by the [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) function.

If the number of arguments you want to pass depends on the length of an array, it probably means you can pack them into an array themselves -- and use that one for the second parameter of `call_user_func_array`.

Elements of that array you pass will then be received by your function as distinct parameters.

For instance, if you have this function :

```
function test() {
  var_dump(func_num_args());
  var_dump(func_get_args());
}
```

You can pack your parameters into an array, like this :

```
$params = array(
  10,
  'glop',
  'test',
);
```

And, then, call the function :

```
call_user_func_array('test', $params);
```

This code will the output :

```
int 3

array
  0 => int 10
  1 => string 'glop' (length=4)
  2 => string 'test' (length=4)
```

ie, 3 parameters ; exactly like iof the function was called this way :

```
test(10, 'glop', 'test');
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. call_user_func_array() is exactly the function I was looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to use call_user_func_array() with an object method call?

Comment: @nohat : you're welcome :-) ;; about using a method of an object : yes, you can, using something like array($obj, 'methodName') as first parameter ;; actually, you can pass any "callback" you want to that function. For more informations about callbacks, see http://php.net/callback#language.types.callback

Answer (score 64):

This is now [possible with PHP 5.6.x](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics), using the ... operator (also known as splat operator in some languages):

Example:

```
function addDateIntervalsToDateTime( DateTime $dt, DateInterval ...$intervals )
{
    foreach ( $intervals as $interval ) {
        $dt->add( $interval );
    }
    return $dt;
}

addDateIntervaslToDateTime( new DateTime, new DateInterval( 'P1D' ), 
        new DateInterval( 'P4D' ), new DateInterval( 'P10D' ) );
```

Comment: The **typed** variable arguments list is a feature introduced in **PHP 7**.

Answer (score 52):

In a new **[Php 5.6](http://php.net/archive/2014.php#id2014-10-16-3)**, you can use `... operator` instead of using `func_get_args()`.

So, using this, you can get all the parameters you pass:

```
function manyVars(...$params) {
   var_dump($params);
}
```

Comment: More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.variadics

Comment: From @fracz link, OP is trying to create a "variadic function."

Answer (score 50):

Since **PHP 5.6**, a variable argument list can be specified with the `...` operator.

```
function do_something($first, ...$all_the_others)
{
    var_dump($first);
    var_dump($all_the_others);
}

do_something('this goes in first', 2, 3, 4, 5);

#> string(18) "this goes in first"
#>
#> array(4) {
#>   [0]=>
#>   int(2)
#>   [1]=>
#>   int(3)
#>   [2]=>
#>   int(4)
#>   [3]=>
#>   int(5)
#> }
```

As you can see, the `...` operator collects the variable list of arguments in an array.

If you need to pass the variable arguments to another function, the `...` can still help you.

```
function do_something($first, ...$all_the_others)
{
    do_something_else($first, ...$all_the_others);
    // Which is translated to:
    // do_something_else('this goes in first', 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

---

Since **PHP 7**, the variable list of arguments can be forced to be **all** of the same type too.

```
function do_something($first, int ...$all_the_others) { /**/ }
```

Answer (score 11):

For those looking for a way to do this with `$object->method`:

```
call_user_func_array(array($object, 'method_name'), $array);
```

I was successful with this in a construct function that calls a variable method_name with variable parameters.

Comment: You can also use `$object->method_name(...$array);`

Comment: Going further, if you want to pass by reference, use `$object->method_name(&...$args);`

Answer (score 5):

You can just call it.

```
function test(){        
     print_r(func_get_args());
}

test("blah");
test("blah","blah");
```

Output:

Array ( [0] => blah ) Array ( [0] => blah [1] => blah )

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the problem is not receiving the parameters, but **calling the function** with a variable number of parameters.

Comment: I didn't understanding the OP correctly, then. An array would definitely be the way to go, then. Then again, he could just pass the array directly into test(), no?

Comment: Passing an array might be a solution too, indeed -- If I understood correctly ^^

Comment: Old question but fyi, an array works fine but passing actual arguments allows you to use PHP's default values for null arguments which saves a lot of ugly checking to see if the array contains particular values.

Answer (score 3):

I wondered, I couldn't find documentation about the possiblity of using **named arguments** (since **PHP 8**) in combination with **variable arguments**. Because I tried this piece of code and I was surprised, that it actually worked:

```
function myFunc(...$args) {
    foreach ($args as $key => $arg) {
        echo "Key: $key Arg: $arg <br>";
    }
}
echo myFunc(arg1:"foo", arg2:"bar");
```

Output:

```
Key: arg1 Arg: foo
Key: arg2 Arg: bar
```

In my opinion, this is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised nobody here has mentioned simply passing and [extract](http://php.net/extract)ing an array. E.g:

```
function add($arr){
    extract($arr, EXTR_REFS);
    return $one+$two;
}
$one = 1;
$two = 2;
echo add(compact('one', 'two')); // 3
```

Of course, this does not provide [argument validation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php).
For that, anyone can use my expect function: https://gist.github.com/iautomation/8063fc78e9508ed427d5

Comment: `extract` should never be used... very bad idea to use that

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the magic method __invoke

(Available since php 5.3)

```
class Foo {
    public function __invoke($method=null, $args=[]){
        if($method){
            return call_user_func_array([$this, $method], $args);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function methodName($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){

    }
}
```

From inside same class:

```
$this('methodName', ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']);
```

From an instance of an object:

```
$obj = new Foo;
$obj('methodName', ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
```

Comment: This is basically using `call_user_func_array` as stated by top voted answer in 2009. Maybe there is a point to wrapping an extra `__invoke` around it - but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, I know, however, none of the answers here really do a good job of simply answer the question.

I just played around with php and the solution looks like this:

```
function myFunction($requiredArgument, $optionalArgument = "default"){
   echo $requiredArgument . $optionalArgument;
}
```

This function can do two things:

If its called with only the required parameter: `myFunction("Hi")`
It will print "Hi default"

But if it is called with the optional parameter: `myFunction("Hi","me")`
It will print "Hi me";

I hope this helps anyone who is looking for this down the road.

Comment: You failed to understand the question. OP was asking about arguments that he didn't have to explicitly *define in the function signature* - yet he can still pass values as arguments to the function. For example, the function signature doesn't have *any* arguments defined (optional or not), but when he requires it, OP can send 45 different values as arguments to the function.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, an improved answer.

```
$some_array = array(
    'some-table' => array(
        'where' => array( 
            'column1 = ? and column2 = ?'
        ),
        'parameter-values' => array(1, 2),
        'html-args' => array('id' => 'id', 'name' => ''),
        'variable-arguments' => array(
            array('value-1', 'title-1'),
            array('value-2', 'title-2'),
            array('value-3', 'title-3'),
        )
    )
);

foreach ( $some_array as $table => $args ) {
    $combo = getTableCombo( 
        $table, 
        $args['where'] ?? array(),
        $args['parameter-values'] ?? array(),
        $args['html-args'] ?? array(),
        ...$args['variable-arguments'] ?? array()
    );
}

function getTableCombo( 
    string $table_name, 
    array $where = array(), 
    array $parameter_values = array(),
    array $html_args = array(), 
    array ...$custom_options
    ) {
    //some codes
}
```

In the above code, We could dynamically call the `getTableCombo` function with a variable argument named `$custom_options`