# How can I compute the intersection of an unknown number of arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

I have an array of arrays, and I want to find the intersection of the contained arrays.

My problem is that the array_intersect function requires the arrays to be explicitly specified in the params. I cannot feed the function with my array-of-arrays.

What can I do?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1504
            [2] => 2181
            [3] => 488
            [4] => 554
            [5] => 1539
            [6] => 494
            [7] => 2022
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51
            [1] => 617
            [2] => 651
            [3] => 788
            [4] => 799
            [5] => 835
            [6] => 863
            [7] => 407
            [8] => 650
            [9] => 783
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`call_user_func_array`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $your_array_here);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function