# How to pass arguments to a function without repeating them so many times?

Tags: php

I'm trying to avoid this:

```
function do_something($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {

   function do_something_else($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {
      // code    
   }

   do_something_else($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5);

   // do other things with the args

}
```

That is, repeating the args over and over especially in situations when there are a lot of args. In this example I need to have a nested function called do_something_else inside the main do_something function. The nested function also makes use of all the same args passed into it's parent. So I must pass those into it and once more repeat all those args when actually executing the do_something function.

Is there a cleaner way to handle this? I know the built in php function `func_get_args()` returns an array of all the arguments inside a function but how to pass these into a child function so that they are available there as well, basically looking for a way to do this without repeating the args so many times?

Comment: Consider putting all your arguments into a class/array.

Comment: Consider this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function

Comment: As far as I know, PHP does not support nested functions. It will break if you call `do_something` twice.

Comment: I'm getting back member listings for a community site. Users can search based on various criteria and the do_something_else function is actually a build_query function which builds the select sql statement based on what the user specified. If the user ommits some optional fields I don't need to  add those to the query's clause so those are passed into the main function and I check to see if they are null or not. If not then I build the qurery to include them. Anyway the reason why it's within it's own function is because...

Comment: I need to execute the query twice, to get the total record count for pagination. So rather than repeat all that code twice I put it inside a function so I can just execute it twice.

Comment: @Jake, BTW PHP is not Java or a lang with equivalent syntax.  There is little point in nesting functions this way as all static PHP functions are global.  Cut and paste is cheap.  The runtime costs on passing 5 vs 1 argument are cheap, if the parameters are a tight collection then maybe they should be object properties and you should be passing the object itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already said it. You can use [`func_get_args()`](http://php.net/func_get_args) for simplicity. Combine it with [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) and you're done:

```
call_user_func_array("do_something_else", func_get_args());
```

Actually there is a small caveat. This will only work in PHP 5.3 and onwards. Before that you need a temporary variable:

```
$args = func_get_args();
call_user_func_array("do_something_else", $args);
```

So, it's not much more concise really. But it already shows the alternative: just refine your function signature to use arguments from an array instead.

Comment: This did it, I was able to use the 1st one as I'm on 5.3.6. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Put your arguments in an object.

Comment: There's no guarantee that the arguments are related in a way that they should be in the same object. In fact, they just as well might be objects already...

Comment: The fact that they're all passed into one function is a relation. And what prevents you from putting objects in an object?

Comment: Could you please provide an example, I am new to OOP.

Comment: @Arjan even still, nested functions has all the signs that an object is a better fit.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with objects in objects. Still, without knowing what do_something() and do_something_else() should do, it's hard to say whether it makes sense to put these arguments all in the same object.

Comment: @BradChristie: True, a proper OO design would make more sense here.

Comment: The fact that you're all passing them into a function makes sense enough, think of your object as a 'function request'.

Answer (score 1):

```
function do_something($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {

  function do_something_else($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {
    echo $arg5;
  }

  call_user_func_array('do_something_else', func_get_args());
}
```

This would only save you one repetation though, namely on calling the `do_something_else` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use data tranfer object ( DTO ).
DTO is an data structure(struct or class ) that uses to transfer data between layers or functions.

Answer (score 0):

For a nested function, you can also let the closure use variables from the surrounding context, using the "use" keyword.  I do this quite frequently:

```
$function = function($var) use ($context1, $context2) {
    // code
}
$function($input1);
$function($input2);
```

It does require PHP 5.3 or later.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just pass an associated array.  Allows for flexibility.

```
function sample($data = array()) {
   print_r($data);
}

sample(array('id'=>123.'category'=>'tv'));
```

Answer (score -1):

You basically give the answer by mentioning `func_get_args()`.

```
function do_something($arg1, $arg2, $arg3, $arg4, $arg5) {

   function do_something_else($args) {
      // code    
   }

   do_something_else(func_get_args());

   // do other things with the args

}
```