# php function variable arguments

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function)

I make my framework in php 
I want to have variable function arguments
ex

if I have 2 parameter

```
    $a,$b;
```

the function become

```
    function name($a,$b);
```

and if I have 3 parameter

```
    $a,$b,$c;
```

the function become

```
    function name($a,$b,$c);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list. Is that what you're looking for? If not, can you just accept an array?