# PHP - string concatenation to produce a pattern

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I would like to generate the variable names based on the for loop condition value.  This is my code.

```
  <?php
    for ( $i = 1; $i < $totalcolumns; $i++ ) 
{
  $pattern1 .= '\$'.'a'.$i'';
}
$pattern = str_repeat ('%d', $totalcolumns);
```

As per the above code, I have defined $pattern to generate %d as per the value of totalcolumns. The $pattern part is perfectly fine in the below loop.

```
while (fscanf ($file,'\''.$pattern.'\'','\''.$pattern1.'\''))
```

So if for example, my totalcolumns value is 3, the above while loop should get expanded as below.

```
while (fscanf ($file,'%d%d%d',$a1,$a2,$a3))
```

The pattern is getting expanded correctly, which I checked using echo statement. However, if I include the code for generating pattern1 my program doesn't produce any output.

I am trying to generate the pattern $a1, $a2, $a3 using the variable pattern1. I am using the string concatenation of PHP but I am not able to see any output in the screen. Can someone please guide me in the right direction?

Comment: where you are printing the output

Comment: I am printing it after defining the $pattern value. However, if I try to print $pattern1 am not getting any output.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to create variable variables. Maybe this will help http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php .

Comment: You don't have a period connecting the pattern correctly at the end, would changing it to this: $pattern1 .= '\$'.'a'.$i.''; help? (added a . after $i and before '')

Comment: Also, you won't loop the entire list unless you do $i < $totalcolumns+1; or $i <= $totalcolumns;

Comment: @kadeHafen, I am getting the output correctly as expected. But I am not able to access that variable in my loop. Is there some other thing I need to do? I also tried to include one more $ to define the variables inside $pattern1. Like this -  $pattern1 .= '$'.'$'.'a'.'1'.'';

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you're asking exactly. What's the 'correct' output? And you can't access what variable in your loop? Where are you trying to access it? After the loop or inside it?  Are you trying to produce a string that has inter-changeable variables built-in?

Answer (score 2):

May be try this :

```
<?php
// You probably might have code here to populate $totalcolumns .
// For test purpose I assumed a value .
    $totalcolumns = 3;

//  Initialize $pattern1
    $pattern1 = '';
//  Make sure weather you need $i < $totalcolumns or $i <= $totalcolumns
    for ( $i = 1; $i < $totalcolumns; $i++ ) 
    {
    //  Your line was $pattern1 .= '\$'.'a'.$i''; which has systax error due to two single quotes before the semicolon
        $pattern1 .= '\$'.'a'.$i;
    }
    echo $pattern1;
```

Will output :

```
\$a1\$a2
```

The above answers your ( actual ) question . But it seems that your need is to call a function with variable number of parameters . If it is the case [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) could help you in something along these lines :

[call_user_func_array](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)
[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)
[How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function)

```
<?php
// You probably might have code here to populate $totalcolumns .
// For test purpose I assumed a value .
    $totalcolumns = 3;

//  Also assuming some values for $a1, $a2, $a3 etc.
    $a1 = 'abc';
    $a2 = 'pqr';
    $a3 = 'xyz';

//  For test purpose I used a string replace it with the actual file handle
    $file = 'File handle';

//  Initialize $pattern
    $pattern = '';

//  Define an array to hold parameters for call_user_func_array
    $parameterArray = array();

//  Put first parameter of fscanf at index 0 of $parameterArray
    $parameterArray[0] = $file;

//  Initialize second parameter of fscanf at index 1 of $parameterArray
    $parameterArray[1] = $pattern;

    $parameterArrayIndex = 2;
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $totalcolumns; $i++ ) 
    {
        $pattern .= '%d';
        $parameterArray[$parameterArrayIndex] = ${"a".($i+1)};  // Variable variables
        $parameterArrayIndex++;
    }

//  Update second parameter of fscanf at index 1 of $parameterArray
    $parameterArray[1] = $pattern;

    var_dump( $parameterArray );

    while( call_user_func_array( 'fscanf', $parameterArray ) )
    {
        //  Do what ever you need to do here
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$totalcolumns = 3
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $totalcolumns; $i++ ){
    $pattern1 .= '$a' . $i . ', ';
}
//remove the last comma and space.
$pattern1 = rtrim($pattern1, ", ");
echo $pattern1;
//$a1, $a2, $a3
```

based fully on:
"I am trying to generate the pattern $a1, $a2, $a3"

I'm pretty sure you don't have to escape a dollar($) sign in single quotes either.

"\$"

'$'

Then if I wanted to do something with the output

```
<?php
$filledInString = str_replace('$a1', "REPLACED!", $pattern1);
$filledInString = str_replace('$a3', "AGAIN!", $filledInString);
echo $filledInString;
//REPLACED!, $a2, AGAIN!
?>
```

Or you could just be looking for variable variables, but maybe this is what you were after. Dunno, hope it helped :-)