# Create function make singleton class PHP

Tags: php

code look like this:

```
function make($class,$singleton,array $params=array())
{
   switch(count($params)) 
    {
        case 0:
            return $class::$singleton();
        case 1:
            return $class::$singleton($params[0]);
        case 2:
            return $class::$singleton($params[0],$params[1]);
        case 3:
            return $class::$singleton($params[0],$params[1],$params[2]);
        case 4:
            return $class::$singleton($params[0],$params[1],$params[2],$params[3]);
        case 5:
            return $class::$singleton($params[0],$params[1],$params[2],$params[3],$params[4]);
        default:
            //do something here...
    }
}
```

example:

```
class Test
{
    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function getInstance($name)
    {
        return new Test;
    }
}

$t=make('Test','getInstance',array('something value here'));
```

it ok, but with class have singleton method have variable large than 5, what's code in default switch? somebody can help me?

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function

Comment: Why don't you just pass the whole array regardless of how bit it is?

Answer (score 0):

You could remove your switch by using [call_user_func_array](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array)

```
function make($class, $singleton, array $params = array())
{
return call_user_func_array(array($class, $singleton), $params);
}
```

Or wait PHP5.6 release and you would be able to do this:

```
return $class:$singleton(...$params);
```