# Creating own PHP framework, How to sending parameters to page controller

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

I'm creating my own framework. It works like this
`localhost/controller/action/firstVariable/second/third`  (And so on...)
My bootstrap look like this:

```
$request        = Util::getInput('request');
$requestList    = explode("/",$request);
$modelName      = @ucwords($requestList[0]);
$action         = @$requestList[1];
$parameters = array_slice($requestList,2);
$controllerName = $modelName.'s'.'Controller';
```

I'm getting parameters from an url and save them in a variable `$parameters`. I would like to send them to the current action in my controller the way Laravel 5 is doing.

Example, in Laravel I specify parameters in the url and thats it.

To call them, I need to do a simple step. Just define them:

```
public function firstAction($first,$second){

}
```

When I go to an url like:
`localhost/Main/firstAction/first/second/`

Function of action 'firstAction' will catch those 2 parameters and then basically I can call them inside of the controller and send it to view.

My extends Controller class:

```
class Controller{
public function __construct($model,$action){
    $modelClass = new main();
    $reflection = new ReflectionClass($model.'sController');
    $reflection->hasMethod($action) ? $this->$action() : die ('Base Controller call error: Method '. $action .' does not exist in Controller '. $model.'sController');

}
public static function renderView($action,$model,$data){
    $model = str_replace('sController','',$model);
    //include '../application/views/'.$model.'/'.$action.'.php';
    $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('../application/views/'.$model);
    $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
    echo $twig->render($action.'.php', $data);
}
```

}

```
class MainsController extends Controller {

private $_data = array();

public function __construct($model,$action){
    parent::__construct($model,$action);
}

public function firstAction($first,$second){
    echo 'Hoi';
}
```

}

How can I do it, the good way? I can of course send the variable $parameter to MainController and than call
$this->_data inside of my action but It is not efficient.
I think I need to use arrays to do it, but I have no idea how.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "in a good way"?

Comment: i want to do it laravel way

Comment: @WorkingPig I'd better use Laravel or Lumen instead of focusing on framework rather than on app itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function)

Comment: @John why would you give someone such an advice? _go use frameworks build by others so you learn absolutely nothing other than to program with someone else's work_? nonsens ..

Comment: @dbf, Why don't you create your own operating system?

Comment: @John been there, done that ..

Comment: @dbf and of course you're using it

Comment: @John I asked you a question, _why would you give someone such an advice_.. But you can also continue adding useless comments ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

P.S.
You do not have to use reflection in order to check if method on that object's instance exist. Single function call can be enough. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php

It would be nice if you would use more descriptive names. Now they are confusing.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I need! Function call_user_func_array! Have a wonderful day!And thanks for second function :)