# Weird issue with parameter validation on usage of interface implementation

Tags: php, laravel, interface, phpstorm

So basically I'm not sure if this is a PhpStorm issue parsing my code or if its a weird quirk of PHP and interfaces but basically I have the following interface

```
<?php

namespace App\Contracts;

/**
 * Interface IFileSource
 * @package App\Contracts
 */
interface IFileSource
{
    public function getFilesByPattern(string $filePattern) : array;
}
```

with the following implementation

```
<?php

namespace App\Sources;

use App\Contracts\IFileService;
use App\Services\File\FileService;

/**
 * Class FileSource
 * @package App\Sources
 */
class FileSource implements IFileSource
{
    /**
     * @var FileService
     */
    private $fileService;

    public function __construct (IFileService $fileService)
    {
        $this->fileService = $fileService;
    }


    /**
     * @param string $filePattern
     * @return File[]
     * NOTE THIS ASSUMES FILESYSTEM
     */
    public function getFilesByPattern (string $filePattern) : array
    {
        $filesDetails = $this->fileService->getFilesByPattern($filePattern);
        return [];
    }
}
```

and the usage

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Contracts\IFileSource;
use App\Sources\FileSource;

class ImportXML extends Command
{

    /**
     * @var FileSource
     */
    protected $fileSource;

    public function __construct (IFileSource $fileSource)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->fileSource = $fileSource;
    }

    public function handle () : void
    {     
            $filePattern = 'APATTERN';
            $files = $this->fileSource->getFilesByPattern($filePattern)
    }
}
```

My question relates to the usage of this implementation.

So the following is a valid usage:

```
$filePattern = 'APATTERN';
$this->fileSource->getFilesByPattern(filePattern)
```

But for some reason the following is also seen as a valid usage?

```
$filePattern = 'APATTERN';
$this->fileSource->getFilesByPattern(filePattern,filePattern,filePattern,filePattern,filePattern,filePattern,filePattern)
```

Why does it not care that i am not conforming to my implementation?

Comment: Always provide a real code sample that can be easily copy pasted and tested locally. In my code it always highlights this as an error. But my code might be different to yours...

Comment: Sorry! i have updated with verbatim code... i thought it would be something more obvious as i can replicate this with any implementation not just one particular implementation

Comment: Haha, sorry but now I think we should try a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the emphasis on minimal

Comment: haha okay third time lucky!

Comment: PhpStorm will correctly report a warning if you use `IFileSource` instead of `FileSource` (well, at least in my test project that has no Laravel code & PHP Language Level was set to 7.2 if that would make any diff). https://postimg.cc/qzk82jp5. Will also work if I use `FileSource` in both PHPDoc typehint for the field and constructor parameter (so it's the same in both paces)

Comment: Cannot say why exactly it does not report an error when interface and concrete class typehints are used at the same time (IDE sees 2 possible signatures: although they are the same ... there are 2 of them...). Could be a bug or IDE specific restriction -- check/report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Thanks! your second comment was another gripe i had that i eventually gave up googling cause time constraints.

Comment: As for the first comment, i thought i had to go about this due to how Dependency injection works with laravel? hopefully someone else can chime in about that

Comment: Your code is OK -- no issues there. But if you are using interfaces (as a parameter typehint) ... then use interfaces in other places as well (field typehint via PHPDoc). There is no much point to typehint using specific class if interfaces are in use (no need to mix them).

Comment: In simple words: interface means "I will be using only methods that are declared in interface .. so I can change to another implementation (concrete class) at any moment". Specifying concrete class in such case (as a typehint) is basically wrong as you may use some method that is absent in interface put present in concrete .. which defeats the purpose of using interface in first place.

Comment: Ah yep, that does make sense. Just so i understand correctly...  

 if DI injects a differing implementation i.e. S3FileService and this adds a new public method called say getBucketContents, How could the usage safely be able to type hint both possibilities? 

 well that wouldn't work cause then the other implementation doesn't have a function and it would just break

so why not just use the interface cause that's the point of interface.

Thanks! its all clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So incase someone else stumbles across this,

thanks to LazyOne for the help explaining what i was doing wrong

it was due to the fact i am enforcing the implementation in the PHPdoc rather than relying on the interface to enforce the type hinting (or adding the interface as the type hint instead of the implementation), once i changed this it began complaining as expected.

Why enforce an implementation when the point of the interface is the enforce such things.

Doh

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it not care that i am not conforming to my implementation

That's the whole point of interfaces - they don't care about implementations. They only care about how the method is defined and if the *signature* conforms to the interface.

However, I think the real question being asked here is why the **PHP interpreter** doesn't throw an exception when multiple arguments are passed to the function. The answer is because this is how PHP implements overloading. They allow a variable number of arguments to be passed which you can access with functions such as `func_get_args`.

You should definitely read https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list and also look into the new(ish) splat operator `...`.

Similar QAs

- [How to pass variable number of arguments to a PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422652/how-to-pass-variable-number-of-arguments-to-a-php-function)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165467/why-php-doesnt-support-function-overloading

Comment: thanks for that!

So maybe the true question i should be asking is there a way to disable method overloading for an implementation? 

i was under the impression that if you needed to have another version of such a function, as in it is an indication that you need to update the design of your implementations/interfaces.

so in mycase if i needed getFilesByPattern to also take the file path seperate to the filename i would make a getFilesByPatternAndPath instead of adding complexity to getFilesByPattern to support an overloaded parameter?

maybe im thinking too small...